# Deleted by accident *.appspot.com bucket, how to recovery?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-scheduler

I deleted by accident `project-id.appspot.com`, `us.artifacts.project-id.appspot.com` and `staging.project-id.appspot.com` buckets created by **cloud scheduler** and now it stopped to work. I can't redeploy again, I can't recreate the buckets because its ended in `appspot.com` (because I need domain verification for that, and of course appspot.com isn't mine.)

How to recovery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should run the command :

```
gcloud beta app repair
```

> (BETA) For example, this command will restore the App Engine staging
> bucket if it has been deleted. It will no longer restore the service
> account, instead, the IAM service account undelete API must be used
> for the purpose.

[gcloud beta app repair - restores required App Engine features to the current application](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair)